# Is there a way to simulate a network so that I can test my p2p network code written in python?

Tags: python, networking, simulation, p2p

I need to be able to run python code on each "node" of the network so that I can test out the code properly. I can't use different port numbers and run the code since I need to handle various other things which kind of force using unique IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my DHT p2p project, I have a specific object that abstract the network communication. During testing I mock that object with an object that operate in memory:

```
class MockProtocol:

    def __init__(self, network, peer):
        self.network = network
        self.peer = peer

    async def rpc(self, address, name, *args):
        peer = self.network.peers[address[0]]
        proc = getattr(peer, name)
        start = time()
        out = await proc((self.peer._uid, None), *args)
        delta = time() - start
        assert delta < 5, "RPCProtocol allows 5s delay only"
        return out


class MockNetwork:

    def __init__(self):
        self.peers = dict()

    def add(self, peer):
        peer._protocol = MockProtocol(self, peer)
        self.peers[peer._uid] = peer

    def choice(self):
        return random.choice(list(self.peers.values()))


async def simple_network():
    network = MockNetwork()
    for i in range(5):
        peer = make_peer()
        network.add(peer)
    bootstrap = peer
    for peer in network.peers.values():
        await peer.bootstrap((bootstrap._uid, None))
    for peer in network.peers.values():
        await peer.bootstrap((bootstrap._uid, None))

    # run connect, this simulate the peers connecting to an existing
    # network.
    for peer in network.peers.values():
        await peer.connect()

    return network

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_dict(make_network):
    network = await make_network()
    # setup
    value = b'test value'
    key = peer.hash(value)
    # make network and peers
    one = network.choice()
    two = network.choice()
    three = network.choice()
    four = network.choice()

    # exec
    out = await three.set(value)

    # check
    assert out == key

    fallback = list()
    for xxx in (one, two, three, four):
        try:
            out = await xxx.get(key)
        except KeyError:
            fallback.append(xxx)
        else:
            assert out == value

    for xxx in fallback:
        log.warning('fallback for peer %r', xxx)
        out = await xxx.get_at(key, three._uid)
        assert out == value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think vmware or virtual box can help you.